# How to properly migrate stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm tasked with transferring a site from an old client server, to a new server. I've done a sqldump from the old server and have imported into the new server, and it's working except for some sql calls done in php with mysqli.

I'm not that familiar with stored procedures, but what I have noticed is the ones that fail are queries that look like this:

`$db->query("call functionName($id)");`

They keep returning `false` on the new server, which makes me think the stored procedure isn't transferring over.

What I've looked into this has led me to believe this is a stored procedure. But when, I look to the methods of exporting it nothing works.

Old site is running on Ubuntu 18.04 / MariaDB 10.3.17 
New site is Ubuntu 18.04 / MariaDB 10.4.7

Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated, feel this is a bit out of what I'm used too.

Edit: Want to show what the sqldump looks like with the parameters `--routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt`

As you can see it's empty, so is it something else other than a stored procedure/function?

```
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'database_name'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-08-07 17:33:52
```

Comment: The [--routines parameter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldump) on the mysqldump didn't work for you?

Comment: No it didn't, when I imported it into the new server it still displays the error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean `

Comment: You can use something like [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net), or the [CLI](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line-interface), to execute a `SELECT` that [list stored procedures and functions in MariaDB database](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mariadb/list-stored-procedures). Does that show any routines?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone looking back at this, my solution ended up being that there was another user in the db who had all the stored procedures under it. That's why we couldn't see the stored procedures.

So just double check user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transfer also the stored procedures and the functions
make following msqldump and import it into the new database.

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt mydb > mydb.sql
```